# How to compare two time fields in python

Tags: python, string, unix

I have to compare two time field strings represented like `"20141020@023158.000033@EDT"`. How can i compare them most optimally in python?

I want to do `>=` type comparsions on such fields which are of type string.

```
val1 = "20141020@030047.006710@EDT"
val2 = "20141020@030047.006710@EDT"

if val1 > = val2:
    <do something>
```

Comment: What's the problem? You can do this kind of comparison in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime    
t=datetime.datetime.strptime("20141020@030047.006710@EDT","%Y%m%d@%H%M%S.%f@%Z")
```

datetime object supports direct compare using >=.

standard python lib may not handle timezones well ,you may need some third-party module like pytz

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module for this.

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to convert the strings into dates then compare them using `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
currentTime=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
print currentTime
time.sleep(5) 
SecondTime=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
print SecondTime
from dateutil.parser import parse
parseSecondTime = parse(SecondTime)
parseCurrentTime = parse(currentTime)
diffOfTime = parseSecondTime - parseCurrentTime
timeDifference=diffOfTime.total_seconds()
print timeDifference
if timeDifference>0:
    print 'SecondTime is greater'
else:
    print 'Current Time is Greater'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick.

```
import time

val1 = "20141020@023158.000033@EDT"
val2 = "20141020@030047.006710@EDT"

a = time.strptime(val1, '%Y%m%d@%H%M%S.%f@%Z')
b = time.strptime(val2, '%Y%m%d@%H%M%S.%f@%Z')
if a >= b:
    <do something>
```